# How Can I extract class value and save in csv using selenium?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How Can I extract the value using selenium and python, My end goal is to store this value in a csv.

What I have tried:

```py
#element=  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='rt-tr-group']")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-form__price")
for value in elements:
    print(value.text)
```

But this returns an empty list?

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niHu3.png)

Comment: Please let me know if my answer resolved your problem or still not?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a wait / delay.
Try this

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".product-form__price")))
time.sleep(0.5)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-form__price")
for value in elements:
    print(value.text)
```

You will need these imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And to initialize the `wait` object with

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

Comment: Getting a time out exception for this particular selector, even though everthing above is working. Strange

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Answer (score 0):

To print the innertexts e.g. *`$53.37`*  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CLASS_NAME* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "product-form__price")))])
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.product-form__price")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='product-form__price']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Getting a timeout Exception in all three of the methods. any idea what might be causing this?